# Conversion TIFF to shp, duplicates polygons

Tags: gdal, line, kml, ogr2ogr, polygonize

The purpose of my project is 512 KML tiles which represents an entire map.

By editing the KML files I realized that there is redundancy of the polylines. So I look for why and it happens to the conversion of .tiff to .shp (polygonization)

gdalinfo gives me this for the input.tiff

```bsh
Driver: GTiff/GeoTIFF
Files: f_0_224.tiff
Size is 8192, 8192
Coordinate System is:
GEOGCS["WGS 84",
    DATUM["WGS_1984",
        SPHEROID["WGS 84",6378137,298.257223563,
            AUTHORITY["EPSG","7030"]],
        AUTHORITY["EPSG","6326"]],
    PRIMEM["Greenwich",0],
    UNIT["degree",0.0174532925199433],
    AUTHORITY["EPSG","4326"]]
Origin = (-180.000000000000000,11.250000000000000)
Pixel Size = (0.001373291015625,-0.001373291015625)
Metadata:
  AREA_OR_POINT=Area
Image Structure Metadata:
  INTERLEAVE=BAND
Corner Coordinates:
Upper Left  (-180.0000000,  11.2500000) (180d 0' 0.00"W, 11d15' 0.00"N)
Lower Left  (-180.0000000,   0.0000000) (180d 0' 0.00"W,  0d 0' 0.01"N)
Upper Right (-168.7500000,  11.2500000) (168d45' 0.00"W, 11d15' 0.00"N)
Lower Right (-168.7500000,   0.0000000) (168d45' 0.00"W,  0d 0' 0.01"N)
Center      (-174.3750000,   5.6250000) (174d22'30.00"W,  5d37'30.00"N)
Band 1 Block=8192x1 Type=Byte, ColorInterp=Palette
  Color Table (RGB with 256 entries)
    0: 0,0,0,255
    1: 255,255,255,255
    [...]
    255: 0,0,0,255
```

I convert the .tiff to .shp with gdal_polygonise.py

```bsh
gdal_polygonize.py input.tiff output.shp -b 1 -f "ESRI Shapefile" input DN
```

ogrinfo gives me this for the output.tiff

```bsh
INFO: Open of `test3.shp'
      using driver `ESRI Shapefile' successful.

Layer name: test3
Metadata:
  DBF_DATE_LAST_UPDATE=2020-01-11
Geometry: Polygon
Feature Count: 3
Extent: (-180.000000, 0.000000) - (-168.750000, 11.250000)
Layer SRS WKT:
GEOGCS["WGS 84",
    DATUM["WGS_1984",
        SPHEROID["WGS 84",6378137,298.257223563,
            AUTHORITY["EPSG","7030"]],
        AUTHORITY["EPSG","6326"]],
    PRIMEM["Greenwich",0,
        AUTHORITY["EPSG","8901"]],
    UNIT["degree",0.0174532925199433,
        AUTHORITY["EPSG","9122"]],
    AUTHORITY["EPSG","4326"]]
DN: Integer (9.0)
OGRFeature(test3):0
  DN (Integer) = 1
  POLYGON ((-176.624450683594 0.817108154296875,-176.6162109375 0.817108154296875,-176.6162109375 0.81573486328125,-176.614837646484 0.81573486328125,-176.614837646484 0.811614990234375,-176.613464355469 0.811614990234375,-176.613464355469 0.81024169921875,-176.612091064453 0.81024169921875,-176.612091064453 0.803375244140625,-176.610717773438 0.803375244140625,-176.610717773438 0.802001953125,-176.612091064453 0.802001953125,-176.612091064453 0.795135498046875,-176.613464355469 0.795135498046875,-176.613464355469 0.79376220703125,-176.618957519531 0.79376220703125,-176.618957519531 0.797882080078125,-176.620330810547 0.797882080078125,-176.620330810547 0.8074951171875,-176.621704101562 0.8074951171875,-176.621704101562 0.811614990234375,-176.623077392578 0.811614990234375,-176.623077392578 0.814361572265625,-176.624450683594 0.814361572265625,-176.624450683594 0.817108154296875))

OGRFeature(test3):1
  DN (Integer) = 1
  POLYGON ((-176.483001708984 0.20050048828125,-176.474761962891 0.20050048828125,-176.474761962891 0.199127197265625,-176.472015380859 0.199127197265625,-176.472015380859 0.19775390625,-176.470642089844 0.19775390625,-176.470642089844 0.196380615234375,-176.467895507812 0.196380615234375,-176.467895507812 0.1922607421875,-176.469268798828 0.1922607421875,-176.469268798828 0.18951416015625,-176.470642089844 0.18951416015625,-176.470642089844 0.188140869140625,-176.485748291016 0.188140869140625,-176.485748291016 0.18951416015625,-176.487121582031 0.18951416015625,-176.487121582031 0.19500732421875,-176.485748291016 0.19500732421875,-176.484375 0.19500732421875,-176.484375 0.19775390625,-176.483001708984 0.19775390625,-176.483001708984 0.20050048828125))

OGRFeature(test3):2
  DN (Integer) = 0
  POLYGON ((-180.0 11.25,-168.75 11.25,-168.75 0.0,-180 0,-180.0 11.25),(-176.470642089844 0.18951416015625,-176.469268798828 0.18951416015625,-176.469268798828 0.1922607421875,-176.467895507812 0.1922607421875,-176.467895507812 0.196380615234375,-176.470642089844 0.196380615234375,-176.470642089844 0.19775390625,-176.472015380859 0.19775390625,-176.472015380859 0.199127197265625,-176.474761962891 0.199127197265625,-176.474761962891 0.20050048828125,-176.483001708984 0.20050048828125,-176.483001708984 0.19775390625,-176.484375 0.19775390625,-176.484375 0.19500732421875,-176.485748291016 0.19500732421875,-176.487121582031 0.19500732421875,-176.487121582031 0.18951416015625,-176.485748291016 0.18951416015625,-176.485748291016 0.188140869140625,-176.470642089844 0.188140869140625,-176.470642089844 0.18951416015625),(-176.624450683594 0.817108154296875,-176.624450683594 0.814361572265625,-176.623077392578 0.814361572265625,-176.623077392578 0.811614990234375,-176.621704101562 0.811614990234375,-176.621704101562 0.8074951171875,-176.620330810547 0.8074951171875,-176.620330810547 0.797882080078125,-176.618957519531 0.797882080078125,-176.618957519531 0.79376220703125,-176.613464355469 0.79376220703125,-176.613464355469 0.795135498046875,-176.612091064453 0.795135498046875,-176.612091064453 0.802001953125,-176.610717773438 0.802001953125,-176.610717773438 0.803375244140625,-176.612091064453 0.803375244140625,-176.612091064453 0.81024169921875,-176.613464355469 0.81024169921875,-176.613464355469 0.811614990234375,-176.614837646484 0.811614990234375,-176.614837646484 0.81573486328125,-176.6162109375 0.81573486328125,-176.6162109375 0.817108154296875,-176.624450683594 0.817108154296875))
```

OGRFeature(test3):0 & OGRFeature(test3):1 are included in OGRFeature(test3):2, what do I forget as a parameter in the gdal_polygonise.py command so that it neither has duplicates ?

I took the example of a "simple" tile, I can modify it by hand but in other more complex tiles I have redundancies of redundancies, the KML are enormous (weight) and it is unmanageable by hand.

Comment: You seem to be using "polygon" and "polyline" as interchangeable terms. They're not, since they refer to distinct topology classes. Any GIS worthy to be called a GIS contains the ability to clip datasets or individual features, and to merge polygons. While GDAL is a powerful tool, it does not replace all the functions of a GIS, and some of those functions are needed in order to continue your processing. Generate a tile grid, overlay each output layer through it, then evaluate the parts which are not it their "proper" tile for elimination. You may also need to edit/repair along boundaries.

Comment: I forgot to say that the polygon from gdal_polygonise.py, I repair it then convert it into lines via QGIS
It didn't seem important to me to report it, sorry.

Answer (score 0):

Misunderstanding on my part about DN's interest ...
DN=0 (Land), DN=1(Sea) with this command it's ok

```bsh
ogr2ogr output.shp input.shp -where "DN=0"
```

```bsh
INFO: Open of `../test/test.shp'
      using driver `ESRI Shapefile' successful.

Layer name: test
Metadata:
  DBF_DATE_LAST_UPDATE=2020-01-11
Geometry: Polygon
Feature Count: 1
Extent: (-180.000000, 0.000000) - (-168.750000, 11.250000)
Layer SRS WKT:
GEOGCS["WGS 84",
    DATUM["WGS_1984",
        SPHEROID["WGS 84",6378137,298.257223563,
            AUTHORITY["EPSG","7030"]],
        AUTHORITY["EPSG","6326"]],
    PRIMEM["Greenwich",0,
        AUTHORITY["EPSG","8901"]],
    UNIT["degree",0.0174532925199433,
        AUTHORITY["EPSG","9122"]],
    AUTHORITY["EPSG","4326"]]
DN: Integer (9.0)
OGRFeature(test):0
  DN (Integer) = 0
  POLYGON ((-180.0 11.25,-168.75 11.25,-168.75 0.0,-180 0,-180.0 11.25),(-176.470642089844 0.18951416015625,-176.469268798828 0.18951416015625,-176.469268798828 0.1922607421875,-176.467895507812 0.1922607421875,-176.467895507812 0.196380615234375,-176.470642089844 0.196380615234375,-176.470642089844 0.19775390625,-176.472015380859 0.19775390625,-176.472015380859 0.199127197265625,-176.474761962891 0.199127197265625,-176.474761962891 0.20050048828125,-176.483001708984 0.20050048828125,-176.483001708984 0.19775390625,-176.484375 0.19775390625,-176.484375 0.19500732421875,-176.485748291016 0.19500732421875,-176.487121582031 0.19500732421875,-176.487121582031 0.18951416015625,-176.485748291016 0.18951416015625,-176.485748291016 0.188140869140625,-176.470642089844 0.188140869140625,-176.470642089844 0.18951416015625),(-176.624450683594 0.817108154296875,-176.624450683594 0.814361572265625,-176.623077392578 0.814361572265625,-176.623077392578 0.811614990234375,-176.621704101562 0.811614990234375,-176.621704101562 0.8074951171875,-176.620330810547 0.8074951171875,-176.620330810547 0.797882080078125,-176.618957519531 0.797882080078125,-176.618957519531 0.79376220703125,-176.613464355469 0.79376220703125,-176.613464355469 0.795135498046875,-176.612091064453 0.795135498046875,-176.612091064453 0.802001953125,-176.610717773438 0.802001953125,-176.610717773438 0.803375244140625,-176.612091064453 0.803375244140625,-176.612091064453 0.81024169921875,-176.613464355469 0.81024169921875,-176.613464355469 0.811614990234375,-176.614837646484 0.811614990234375,-176.614837646484 0.81573486328125,-176.6162109375 0.81573486328125,-176.6162109375 0.817108154296875,-176.624450683594 0.817108154296875))
```